# AngularJS and Jasmine, inject() causes error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Im writing tests with karma + jasmine. Look at this:

```
describe("users module", function(){

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('users');
    });

    it("should work", function(){

    });

});
```

The above code is working and i get this output

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.038 secs / 0.001 secs)
```

What i really need to do here is testing that module controllers. So i am adding:

```
describe("users module", function(){

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('users');
    });

    describe("Users list", function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('ctrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));

        it("should work", function(){

        });
    });
});
```

When i add the second `beforeEach` block i get an injection error. The error dump is **huge**, it starts like so:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=users
```

I've tried to dry the code as much as possible but even the following leads to the same error:

```
describe("users module", function(){

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('users');
    });

    describe("Users list", function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function () {

        }));

        it("should work", function(){

        });
    });
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

**==EDIT==**

If i switch to non-minified angular version i get a readable error dump, which looks like as follows:

```
public/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4632:53
        forEach@public/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
        loadModules@public/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4592:12
        createInjector@public/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4514:30
        workFn@public/src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3067:60
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
```

Comment: You should open the karma webclient, and inspect it with your devtools for better readable stacks. By default you can find it at: http://localhost:9876/debug.html. My fist guess would be that your controller depends on a service that is not defined in the users-module. And that you should inject that dependency in your tests as well.

Comment: Uhm, but it does crash even if i try NOT to inject the controller.

Comment: ah, but it still works when you don't put the describe in? Then I can only suggest using Chrome to debug the error, because this looks like it surpassed my knowledge :)

Comment: I had a typo in module dependencies :(

Comment: now, that's something I can realate to :D

Answer (score 1):

It turned out i misspelled a module dependency.

Lesson: if angular's saying it has troubles creating module `users`, that's most probably true and you *must* investigate that error first.